# Create JPA predicates without .createCriteriaBuilder call?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a Hibernate Expression in my service layer, that I would like to migrate to a Predicate for CriteriaBuilder:

```
SimpleExpression criterionSupplier = Property.forName("supplierId").eq(supplierId);
SimpleExpression criterionRfq = Property.forName("rfqId").eq(rfqId);
```

Which would look like:

```
Predicate supplierPredicate = cb.equal(root.get("supplierId"), supplierId);
Predicate supplierPredicate = cb.equal(root.get("rfqId"), rfqId);
```

As this is the service layer, I do not have available a session here to create CriteriaBuilder/Root. Is it possible to create predicates without CriteriaBuilder or do I have to inject the Hibernate SessionFactory in my service class?

Answer (score 0):

You can't construct predicates without a `SessionFactory`. The usual approach to this is, to create a class with a method, that create the predicate based on a given `Query`, `Root` and `CriteriaBuilder`. In Spring Data JPA, this abstraction has the name `Specification`.